Symbolic integral over real functions with interger parametres evaluates to complex numbers
I want to compute some quantum mechanical matrix elements. I use that:
psiGeneral[n_, x_] := Piecewise[{{Sqrt[2/Pi]  Sin[n  x], Mod[n, 2] == 1}, {Sqrt[2/Pi]  Cos[n  x], Mod[n, 2] == 0}}];

matrixIntegralGeneral[n_, m_] :=
  Assuming[{x \[Element] Reals, y \[Element] Reals,n \[Element] Integers, m \[Element] Integers, n > 0, m > 0},
   (Integrate[psiGeneral[n, x]  psiGeneral[m, y]  (y  D[psiGeneral[1, x]  psiGeneral[1, y], x]), {x, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {y, -Pi/2, Pi/2}] -
   Integrate[psiGeneral[n, x]  psiGeneral[m, y]  (x  D[psiGeneral[1, x]  psiGeneral[1, y], y]), {x, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {y, -Pi/2, Pi/2}])];

Simplify[matrixIntegralGeneral[n, m]]

I obtiain some complex number result,
(32 I^(m + n) (m^2 - n^2))/((-1 + m^2)^2 (-1 + n^2)^2 \[Pi]^2)

which is impossible because everything is real in this computation. I can imagine that MMA internally uses complex representations of the trigon. functions, however the final simplified result should be real.
I have a vague suspicion that some factors are cancelled somehow in the simplification such that the simplified result does not represent the correct result anymore.
What can I do to solve the problem and obtain the correct symbolic result?

BTW, psiGeneral[n_, x_] :=  Piecewise[{{Sqrt[2/Pi] Sin[n x], OddQ[n]}, {Sqrt[2/Pi] Cos[n x],     EvenQ[n]}}];Integrate[ psiGeneral[n, x] psiGeneral[m,      y] (y  D[psiGeneral[1, x] psiGeneral[1, y], x]), {x, -Pi/2,     Pi/2}, {y, -Pi/2, Pi/2},   Assumptions -> {n \[Element] Integers, m \[Element] Integers, n > 0,,   m > 0}] -   Integrate[  psiGeneral[n, x] psiGeneral[m,      y] (x  D[psiGeneral[1, x] psiGeneral[1, y], y]), {x, -Pi/2,     Pi/2}, {y, -Pi/2, Pi/2},   Assumptions -> {n \[Element] Integers, m \[Element] Integers, n > 0,     m > 0}] outputs 0, hough psiGeneral[3, x]

results in Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] Sin[3 x]. Definitely a bug.

Maybe you can use
psiGeneral[n_, x_] := 
 Sqrt[2/Pi] (Sin[n x] ((-1)^(n + 1) + 1)/2 + Cos[n x] ((-1)^n + 1)/2)

instead.

Very clever! Thank you!!

Your psiGeneral[n_, x_] :=   Sqrt[2/Pi] (Sin[n x] ((-1)^(n + 1) + 1)/2 + Cos[n x] ((-1)^n + 1)/2) is constructed by hand, not with Mathematica.

As QP suspects integration using Assuming fails in this case. User @JieZhu gave a workaround which can be confirmed as follows:
psiGeneral[n_, x_] := 
  Piecewise[{{Sqrt[2/Pi] Sin[n x], 
     Mod[n, 2] == 1}, {Sqrt[2/Pi] Cos[n x], Mod[n, 2] == 0}}];
solnm = Table[{n, 
   m, (Integrate[
      psiGeneral[n, x] psiGeneral[m, 
        y] (y D[psiGeneral[1, x] psiGeneral[1, y], x]), {x, -Pi/2, 
       Pi/2}, {y, -Pi/2, Pi/2}] - 
     Integrate[
      psiGeneral[n, x] psiGeneral[m, 
        y] (x D[psiGeneral[1, x] psiGeneral[1, y], y]), {x, -Pi/2, 
       Pi/2}, {y, -Pi/2, Pi/2}]) }, {n, 1, 6}, {m, 1, 6}]


Result shows that @user64494' answer isn't correct!
Hope it helps!

And a warning/error "SetDelayed::write: Tag Times in as (follows:[Piecewise] Sqrt[Times[<<2>>]] Sin[Times[<<2>>]] Mod[Pattern[<<2>>],2]==1
Sqrt[Times[<<2>>]] Cos[Times[<<2>>]] Mod[Pattern[<<2>>],2]==0
0 True
) is Protected."

@user64494 Mathematica v12.2 doesn't show any warnings

After a slight improvement in psiGeneral[n_, x_] (x is determinated as real-valued) and  moving the assumptions in Integrate your code works correctly.
psiGeneral[n_, x_] := Piecewise[{{Sqrt[2/Pi] Sin[n x], 
 Mod[n, 2] == 1 && x \[Element] Reals}, {Sqrt[2/Pi] Cos[n x], 
 Mod[n, 2] == 0 && x \[Element] Reals}}];
matrixIntegralGeneral[n_,  m_] := (Integrate[
 psiGeneral[n, x] psiGeneral[m, 
   y] (y D[psiGeneral[1, x] psiGeneral[1, y], x]), {x, -Pi/2, 
  Pi/2}, {y, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, 
 Assumptions -> {n \[Element] Integers, m \[Element] Integers, 
   n > 0, m > 0}] - 
Integrate[
 psiGeneral[n, x] psiGeneral[m, 
   y] (x D[psiGeneral[1, x] psiGeneral[1, y], y]), {x, -Pi/2, 
  Pi/2}, {y, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, 
 Assumptions -> {n \[Element] Integers, m \[Element] Integers, 
   n > 0, m > 0}])//Simplify;
matrixIntegralGeneral[n, m]


Piecewise[{{(32*I^(m + n)*(m^2 - n^2))/ ((-1 + m^2)^2*(-1 + n^2)^2*Pi^2), Mod[m, 2] == 0 &&  Mod[n, 2] == 0}}, 0]

In fact, this is a real-valued expression. I am not able to remove I^(m+n) which equals 1.

It appears iI is not necessary to move the assumptions in Integrates. Enough to modify siGeneral[n_, x_] only.

It works with psiGeneral[n_, x_] :=    Piecewise[{{Sqrt[2/Pi] Sin[n x],       Mod[n, 2] == 1 && x \[Element] Complexes}, {Sqrt[2/Pi] Cos[n x],       Mod[n, 2] == 0 && x \[Element] Complexes}}]; too. In view of it I think the reason of the wrong answer obtained by the OP consists in the following: the OP  does not determinate x, though psiGeneral[n_, x_] is a function of two arguments.

Regarding difference between use of Integrate[...,Assumptions->...] vs. Assuming...,Integrate[...]], see this old MSE response.

@DanielLichtblau? Thank you for your valuable comment. The state of things may change during last 10 years.

In regards to the link I sent, I can quite assure you they have not changed as yet.
